# A parameters' variable as parameter

Tags: java, function, variables, object, parameters

I have an Object Human:

```
public class Human {
String name;

public Human(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

In my main Class I have an instance of this human "John".
With a function called getVarOfObject() I want to get John's name:

```
public class Example {

public static Object getVarOfObject(Object obj, Object var){

    return obj.var;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Human john = new Human("John");

    String johnsName = getVarOfObject(john, name);

}

}
```

I know you could just type john.name but in my case I need to have a function which can do this.

Comment: To me, this is over complicating the program.  You want to make the code as simple as possible. If you start adding things like this in, it'll take a few reads over to fully comprehend the logic.

Comment: @BenjaminDale It can be made straightforward if reflection is used correctly and sparingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code

```
        Field field = <Your object>.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return (String) field.get(object);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this except reflectively.

Please note that this wizardry can lead to errors, subtle issues, exceptions, performance losses, asphyxiation, drowning, death, paralysis, or fire.

Object `obj` is the object, and String `field` is the name of the field.

```
Class clazz=Human.getClass(); //or for class-independence use `obj.getClass()`.
Field fd=clazz.getField(name);
fd.get(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use accessor methods (getters and setters)?

In `Human`:

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

and in your main method:

```
Human john = new Human("John");
String johnsName = john.getName();
```

Comment: I want to use a function where I would have to create an interface to make sure the object has a getName() method. But maybe I don't want to get the Name but another variable. This method would be very unflexible.